# Draw an arrow between nodes in forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to create an arrow between two nodes like the red one in below example.

[image: Example Tree]

I've seen the following in documentation, but tbh I don't understand how to use it and I need to use it in more than one tree.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Show us what you have done so far so that we can help you complete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works precisely as described in the documentation...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{state/.style={draw,circle}}
\forestset{d/.style={dotted,edge=dotted},
r/.style={red,edge=red}}
\begin{forest}
for tree={state,edge={-},grow=south,l sep=6mm,s sep=10mm},
[22,d
 [13,d
  [30,red,edge=dotted
   [15,r]
   [85,r]{\draw[<->,red] () to[bend right=45] node[midway,above
   right,font=\small]{zam} (!u.east);}
  ]
  [71
   [17]
   [20]
  ]
 ]
 [11,d
  [33,edge=dotted
   [32]
  ]
  [55,d]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @kkiermasz The same thing. Just add after the closing `]` in the line below that arrow `{\draw[<->,red] (.north) to[bend left=45] node[midway,above
   left,font=\small]{zam} (!u.west);}`. Why does that work? Because `()` is the current node, i.e. the one after which you place the command, `(.north)` is its north anchor, and `(!u)` is its parent. The example in the manual is slightly more complex in that `(!us)` is the sibling of the parent (i.e. aunt or uncle).